# Upgrade Magento Enterprise Edition with version 1.14.2.1 to the latest 1.14.3.8

Tags: magento-1

I wish to upgrade my Magento Enterprise Edition with version 1.14.2.1 to the latest 1.14.3.8 - and I can not seem to find any documentation on how to perform the upgrade from 1.14.2.1.

Can someone please share with me any of their experiences they've had with doing this particular upgrade?

Can someone point me to the correct upgrade article?

Comment: send me details i can update

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but can you please tell me the step by step process?

Comment: IF USEFULL PLEASE VOTE ME